# Magento where to look for totals code?

Tags: magento-1.9

Where should I look (in which directory or database) for this code:

```
 $config = Mage::getConfig()->getNode("global/sales/quote/totals/{$code}/renderer");
```

it has to be some template I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear whether you are looking for this line of code or its source:

since  `Mage::getConfig()->getNode()` directly reads from configuration files.
So You should be looking at `Config.xml` files(in this case it might be `Checkout/etc/config.xml`) for the source.

**Example**:

```
<default>
    <catalog>
        <mypage>                
            <name>myname</name>                                
            <age>100</age>
            <address_one>earth</address_one>                
        </mypage>        
    </catalog>
</default>
```

Here is the code to read the node of the above XML file. Here, ‘catalog/mypage‘ is parent nodes path. It depends upon XML node layout.

```
// prints 'myname'
echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('catalog/mypage')->name;

// prints '100'
echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('catalog/mypage')->age;

// prints 'earth'
echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('catalog/mypage')->address_one;
```

Or if you are looking for this particular code `" $config = Mage::getConfig()->getNode("global/sales/quote/totals/{$code}/renderer");"`

It will be in either in  `.phtml files, controllers , models,blocks,or helpers`